# Update indicator label in c#

Tags: indicator, c#

I've created a new indicator:

```
indicator = 
        new ApplicationIndicator (
            "sample-application",       //id of the the indicator icon
            "app-icon",                 //file name of the icon (will look for app-icon.png) 
            Category.ApplicationStatus, 
            ExecutableFolder            //the folder where to look for app-icon.png
        );  

        //Build Popup Menu for ApplicationIndicator
        Menu popupMenu = new Menu ();
        indicator.Label = "init label";
...
```

From a timer callback, function I want to update the indicator's label:

```
indicator.label = "new label";
```

The new label value is not applied to the indicator. It still shows the `init label` string.

Comment: To CLOSE queue Reviewers, [libappindicator](https://launchpad.net/libappindicator) is an upstream project in Ubuntu (part of [Unity User Services](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-menu-bar)). It shouldn't be off-topic, right?

Comment: The label is changed, the problem is with the UI update !

Comment: It should be `indicator.Label = "new label";` with capital `L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think it just that typo, It should be `indicator.Label = "new label";` with capital `L`.
- Here is my complete working showcase (Tested on Ubuntu 14.04):

  1. `indicator_demo.cs`

     ```
     using Gtk;
     using AppIndicator;

     public class IndicatorExample
     {
             static Window win;
             static  ApplicationIndicator indicator;
             static int c;


             public static void Main ()
             {
                     Application.Init ();

                     win = new Window ("Test");
                     win.Resize (200, 200);

                     Label label = new Label ();
                     label.Text = "Hello, world!";

                     win.Add (label);

                     indicator = new ApplicationIndicator ("my-id",
                                                                                "my-name",
                                                                                Category.ApplicationStatus);

                     indicator.Status = Status.Attention;


                     Menu menu = new Menu ();
                     //menu.Append (new MenuItem ("Foo"));
                     //menu.Append (new MenuItem ("Bar"));

                     indicator.Menu = menu;
                     indicator.Menu.Show();
                     indicator.Label = "init label";                

                     win.ShowAll ();

                     indicator.Label = "label2";
                     c = 0;
                     GLib.Timeout.Add (1000, new GLib.TimeoutHandler (update));

                     Application.Run ();
             }

             public static bool update()
             {
                     c+=1;
                     indicator.Label = c.ToString();

                     return true;
             }
     }
     ```

     This was a mod of [Ubuntu Wiki: Application Indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) C# example.
  2. Compile & Run to test:

     ```
     dmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 -pkg:appindicator-sharp-0.1 indicator_demo.cs
     mono indicator_demo.exe
     ```

Comment: Thank you the solution works perfectly ! 
It seems that using System.Timers.Timer instead of Glib.Timeout produce problems in updating indicator label.